# How to create multiple output files with npm scripts?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I am trying npm scripts instead of gulp. And I've ran into the issue, could I have one npm script, for example, to compile scss files with node-sass for development and for prod or should I have multiple scripts for that purposes:

here is my **package.json**:

```json
...

"scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass app/src/styles/main.scss --output app/.tmp/styles/",
    "autoprefixer": "postcss -u autoprefixer -r app/.tpm/styles/*",
    "scss:prod": "node-sass app/src/styles/main.scss --output app/dist/styles/",
    "autoprefixer:prod": "postcss -u autoprefixer -r app/dist/styles/*",
    "cssnano": "postcss -u cssnano -r app/dist/styles/main.css",
    "build:styles": "npm run scss:prod && npm run autoprefixer:prod && npm run cssnano"
},
```

Is it possible to split my scss task into single script with multiple outputs for dev and prod folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**short answer: It's best to use multiple scripts for that purpose**

---

For example:

```json
...
"scss:dev": "node-sass app/src/styles/main.scss --output app/dev/styles/"
"scss:prod": "node-sass app/src/styles/main.scss --output app/dist/styles/"
...
```

*(Note the only difference is to the output/destination path)*

Then consider grouping all the styles related tasks as `dev` or `prod`. For example:

```json
...
"build-styles:prod": "npm run scss:prod && ..."
"build-styles:dev": "npm run scss:dev && ..."
...
```

You can also aim to have one script for `dev` and one for `build` that does all the tasks, i.e. those in addition to just handling the styles related tasks. For example:

```json
...
"dev": "build-styles:dev && ..." 
"build": "build-styles:prod && ..."
...
```

Then you can simply run either `$ npm run dev` or `$ npm run build` via your CLI as necessary and all the tasks are carried out.

***Note***: You will find that *sometimes* a script name does not need to be distinguished with either a `:prod` or `:dev` suffix as one script can serve either purpose (both `dev` or `build`). However, typically when output/destination paths differ then consider prefixing with either `:dev` or `:prod` as necessary.

---

**Why ?**

Yes, admittedly it's rather verbose and not particularly [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), yet it's easier for humans to read and maintain. IMO *"easier to read"* and better maintainability wins every time.

Besides, you may find that sometimes it's not only the output/destination path that differs between the requirements for `dev` and `build`. As an example, for `dev` purposes you *may* want to your task named `"scss:dev"` to also include sourceMaps [option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#usage-1) for easier debugging - yet you don't particularly want source maps included with the final build/dist code.

---

**But, I must have one script or the world's gonna stop spinning :)**

> Is it possible to split my scss task into single script with multiple outputs for dev and prod folders?

Yes it's possible to have one script. Given the script named `"scss"` in your OP you could use chaining (`&&`) like this:

```json
...
"scss": "node-sass app/src/styles/main.scss --output app/.tmp/styles/ && node-sass app/src/styles/main.scss --output app/dist/styles/"
...
```

Or, with an additional project dependency:

```json
...
"scss": "node-sass app/src/styles/main.scss --output app/.tmp/styles/ && catw app/.tmp/styles/main.css > app/dist/styles/main.css"
...
```

This compiles the `main.scss` which outputs an initial `main.css`. We then `cat` the `main.css` and output a duplicate copy to the `dist` folder. *(Note: This is using [catw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/catw) instead of [cat](https://ss64.com/bash/cat.html) because `cat` does not work cross platform)*